# .Net 7 unable to mock Identity's FindByIdAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-identity

I am trying to mock Identity's FindByIdAsync, but I keep getting this error

"CS1929: 'ISetup<UserManager, Task<TUser»* does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<ApplicationUser4SetupSequentialResult<Task<ApplicationUser», ApplicationUser)* requires a receiver of type 'ISetupSequentialResult<Task<ApplicationUser»* "

My code is:

```
        public static Mock<UserManager<TUser>> MockManager<TUser>(List<TUser> ls) where TUser : class
        {
            var store = new Mock<IUserStore<TUser>>();
            var mgr = new Mock<UserManager<TUser>>(store.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            mgr.Object.UserValidators.Add(new UserValidator<TUser>());
            mgr.Object.PasswordValidators.Add(new PasswordValidator<TUser>());

            mgr.Setup(um => um.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
            mgr.Setup(um => um.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success).Callback<TUser, string>((x, y) => ls.Add(x));
            mgr.Setup(um => um.UpdateAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
            mgr.Setup(um => um.CheckPasswordAsync(It.IsAny<TUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
            mgr.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(new ApplicationUser()).As<Task<ApplicationUser>>(); //Here where error occurs 

            return mgr;
        }
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Identity uses EF Core. Instead of mocking Identity you can provide test DbContexts using eg the in-memory provider

Comment: Besides, a `Task<ApplicationUser>` is a *task*, not a value. You'd need to use eg `Task.FromResult` to produce a completed task with an actual value